# Storing parameters in .asoundrc does not apply

Tags: audio, audio-recording, alsa

I have a microphone and I can record voice like so:

```
arecord test.wav -r 22050 -f S32_LE -V mono
```

So far so good. However, when a [third party software](https://github.com/dchote/talkiepi) that I'm using (which I think uses ffmpeg internally), wants to use the microphone it fails, since it does not use the above described parameters.

I tried now to move those parameters into my `.asoundrc` so that they will be picked up by alsa.

[The Alsa Wiki](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Asoundrc#Plugins) tells me that the `plug` plugin can be used in order to specify the `rate` and the `format`:

> A more complex tool for conversion is the pcm type plug. the syntax
>   is:
>
> ```
> type plug                  # Format adjusted PCM
> slave STR               # Slave name (see pcm_slave)
> # or
> slave {                 # Slave definition
>         pcm STR         # Slave PCM name
>         # or
>         pcm { }         # Slave PCM definition
>         [format STR]    # Slave format (default nearest) or "unchanged"
>         [channels INT]  # Slave channels (default nearest) or "unchanged"
>         [rate INT]      # Slave rate (default nearest) or "unchanged"
> }
> route_policy STR        # route policy for automatic ttable generation
>                         # STR can be 'default', 'average', 'copy', 'duplicate'
>                        # average: result is average of input channels
>                         # copy: only first channels are copied to destination
>                         # duplicate: duplicate first set of channels
>                        # default: copy policy, except for mono capture - sum
> ttable {               # Transfer table (bidimensional compound of 
>                        # cchannels * schannels numbers)
>         CCHANNEL {
>                 SCHANNEL REAL     # route value (0.0 ... 1.0)
>         }
> }
> ```

So I setup a plugin like so:

```
pcm.!default {
    type            asym
    playback.pcm {
        type        plug
        slave.pcm   "softvol"
    }
    capture.pcm {
        type plug
        slave {
          pcm "plughw:0" # this works
          rate 22050 # does not apply
          format S32_LE # does not apply
        }
    }
}
```

The `pcm "plughw:0"` gets picked up however, the rate and the format fall back to 8 Bit and 8000Hz. Also I have to specify `-V Mono` so that I can record:

```
arecord test.wav -V mono
Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
############+                                     |
```

So unfortunately none of the required parameters can be added to my settings.

### Update

I tried to record using `ffmpeg` in an attempt to mimic what :

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 1 -i plughw:0 output.wav -ar 22050 -f S32_LE
```

The recording starts but no audio is recorded and the rate and format are mixed up again:

```
aplay output2.wav 
Playing WAVE 'output2.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

### Update with `asym` plugin

I did try an asymmetric approach as suggested.

```
pcm.my_mic {
   type hw  
   card 0
   channels 1
   format S32_LE
}

pcm.duplex {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "dmixer"
    capture.pcm "my_mic"
}

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex"
}
```

However, when I enter `arecord test.wav` I'm asked for the format despite the fact that it's configured in the `.asoundrc`.

When I do enter a format I get the following error:

```
arecord -f S32_LE
Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
ALSA lib pcm_params.c:2162:(snd1_pcm_hw_refine_slave) Slave PCM not usable
arecord: set_params:1270: Broken configuration for this PCM: no configurations available.
```

### Update

With some ALSA magic by my friend Y.W. I was able to get arecord to work without parameters, however, it's still somehow using inferior settings when recording audio by default.
The key here it seems was to map the mono signal of my I2s card to a stereo signal.

This is the `.asoundrc` content:

```
# This section makes a reference to your I2S hardware, adjust the card name
# to what is shown in arecord -l after card x: before the name in []
# You may have to adjust channel count also but stick with default first
pcm.dmic_hw {
  type hw
  card raspisound  
  channels 2
  format S32_LE
  rate 48000
}

# This is the software volume control, it links to the hardware above and after
# saving the .asoundrc file you can type alsamixer, press F6 to select
# your I2S mic then F4 to set the recording volume and arrow up and down to adjust the volume
# After adjusting the volume - go for 50 percent at first, you can do something like
# arecord -D dmic_sv -c2 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -t wav -V mono -v myfile.wav
pcm.dmic_sv {
  type softvol
  slave.pcm dmic_hw
  control {
    name "Boost Capture Volume"
    card raspisound
  }
  min_dB -3.0
  max_dB 30.0
}

# This plugin converts the mono input to stereo.
pcm.mono2stereo {
  type route
  slave.pcm dmic_sv
  slave.channels 2
  # ttable.input_channel.output_channel volume_gain
  ttable.0.0 1
  ttable.0.1 1
}

# The "plug" plugin converts channels, rate and format on request.
# In our case it converts the 32 format to whatever the application request.
pcm.convert {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm mono2stereo
  }
}

pcm.convertplayback {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:0"
  }
}

# Default capture and playback devices
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm convert
  playback.pcm convertplayback
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By specifying the slave PCM device as `plughw:0`, you have created a chain of two `plug` plugins. This means that the application can use whatever sample format it pleases, the upper plugin will convert it to 22 kHz with 32 bits, and the lower plugin will convert it to any format the hardware supports.

To force the hardware to use the specified format, use it directly as slave, with `hw:0`.

You cannot prevent programs like `arecord` from using a different format; that is the whole purpose of the `plug` plugin. To check what format is actually used by the hardware, add the `-v` parameter to the `arecord` call.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. What I want is to move the parameters `-r 22050 -f S32_LE -V mono` into my .asoundrc. I know that these options work and I am also fine using `hw` instead of `plughw`. However, when I configure the default device with the format and rate then arecord will ask me for the format. So my question is how to make the working parameters the default for my mic.

Comment: @Besi That might not be possible, as documented in the manpage, `arecord` uses a default rate of 8kHz and U8 format. When the device is a plugin, ALSA does resampling conversion automagically to 8kHz and U8 even if it's not a mode supported by the actual hardware device.

Comment: As you can see in my example alsa has means of configuring rate, channels and format so why can't I set those?

Comment: When you do not give it other parameters, `arecord` explicitly asks for 8 kHz. If the device does not support that, `arecord` will use the nearest sample rate is supported, but with the `plug` plugin, it is possible to give `arecord` the 8 kHz that it wants. (It would be possible for a program to ask for sample rates that are actually supported without conversion, but `arecord` does not do this for historical reasons.)

Comment: @CL. But is it somehow possible to configure those parameters in my alsa config. As you see in my example alsa provides `rate`, `format` and `channels` in its settings, but they're simply ignored.

Comment: They are not ignored; that device runs with the specified format. But the `plug` device on top allows `arecord` to use a different format.

Comment: Like @CL mentioned, `arecord` requests for `-r 8000 -f U8` if nothing is specified. If this sampling rate isn't supported by the device, the closest is selected. However, it does no format conversion, and if `U8` isn't supported, you will get an error.

Comment: Oh, I looked at your `ffmpeg` command too, it's unlikely to be doing what you want it to do. `ffmpeg`'s args is a beast and it's sort of order dependent. You might want to try `ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 1 -ar 22500 -acodec pcm_s32le -i plughw:0 -t 10 -c:a pcm_s32le out.wav` instead